# Asynchronous interactive Python script

Tags: python, multithreading

I'm trying to write a simple Python script to interface with a chat server. It would poll the server for updates, and allow the user to enter text to send to the server as chat. I can kind of get something hacked together with multithreading, but it looks terrible. Is there a nice, simple way to display updating information on the screen while also accepting user input? I'd prefer to do it without curses.

Comment: To do two tasks like that at once, you need threads. You need to have a thread to handle user input, probably the main thread. Then create another thread to handle responses coming from the chat server.

Comment: I got that part working, but it doesn't display right. I've been using raw_input to get input, and it gets messed up when you print out text after it's called.

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - not quite true — some (G)UI toolkits and communications frameworks use a non-threaded loop (often based on `select`), eg. PyGTK and Twisted.

Comment: What's wrong with curses?  Seems really well suited to the problem.  [`pudb`](https://github.com/inducer/pudb) is probably a simple example.

Comment: @detly I'm not very familiar with the `select` system call, from what I just looked up it seems that `select` waits for certain file descriptors to change before doing something. How can this run concurrently? It seems like it is just a busy-wait loop. I may just not understand the `select` call though

Comment: @HunterMcMillen - it's not concurrent, but I/O tasks are interleaved in enough of a fine-grained way that the UI is still responsive. The answer to ["how do twisted/tornado et cetera work"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3067640/how-do-twisted-tornado-et-cetera-work) goes into it a bit.

Comment: @detly thank you for the link, it was very informative.

Answer (score 0):

Let the display window/screen be powered by a temp local db.

Code 1:
Updates the screen from db. You can use infinite loop with or without a pause (screen refresh rate)

Code 2:
Updates the db no sooner the user enters something

Code 3: 
Continuously check for updates from Chat Server and updates the db no sooner a new resposes are received.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to code with ncurses, but here's a solution with wxWidget. It should be roughly similar regarding the design.

```
"""Asynchronous interactive Python script"""
import random
import threading
import wx
import wx.lib.mixins.listctrl as listmix

LOCK = threading.Lock()

def threadsafe(function):
    """A decorator that makes a function safe against concurrent accesses."""
    def _decorated_function(*args, **kwargs):
        """Replacement function."""
        with LOCK:
            function(*args, **kwargs)
    return _decorated_function


class SharedList(wx.ListCtrl, listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin):
    """An output list that can print information from both the user and the server.

    N.B.: The _print function that actually updates the list content uses the threadsafe decorator.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, pos=wx.DefaultPosition, size=(-1, -1), style=wx.LC_REPORT):
        wx.ListCtrl.__init__(self, parent, wx.ID_ANY, pos, size, style)
        self.InsertColumn(0, 'Origin', width=75)
        self.InsertColumn(1, 'Output')
        listmix.ListCtrlAutoWidthMixin.__init__(self)
        self.resizeLastColumn(1000)
        self._list_index = 0

    def user_print(self, text):
        """Print a line as the user"""
        self._print("user", text)

    def chat_print(self, text):
        """Print a line as the chat server"""
        self._print("chat", text)

    @threadsafe
    def _print(self, origin, text):
        """Generic print function."""
        self.InsertStringItem(self._list_index, str(origin))
        self.SetStringItem(self._list_index, 1, str(text))
        self.EnsureVisible(self.GetItemCount() - 1)
        self._list_index = self._list_index + 1


class ServerChecker(threading.Thread):
    """A separate thread that would connect to the IRC chat."""

    def __init__(self, shared_list):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        self._shared_list = shared_list

    def run(self):
        """Connection to the server, socket, listen, bla bla bla."""
        while not self._stop_event.is_set():
            self._shared_list.chat_print("bla bla bla")
            self._stop_event.wait(random.randint(1, 3))

    def stop(self):
        """Stop the thread."""
        self._stop_event.set()


class SampleFrame(wx.Frame):
    """The main GUI element."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(SampleFrame, self).__init__(parent=None, title='DAS Board', size=(600, 400))
        self._shared_list = None
        self._user_text = None
        self._init_ui()
        self._thread = ServerChecker(self._shared_list)
        self._thread.start()
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self._on_close)
        self.Center()
        self.Show()

    def _init_ui(self):
        """Building and assembling the graphical elements.
        Don't pay too much attention, especially if you want to use ncurses instead.
        """
        panel = wx.Panel(self)
        self._shared_list = SharedList(panel)
        main_box_v = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        main_box_v.Add(self._shared_list, proportion=1, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)
        self._user_text = wx.TextCtrl(panel, -1, value="User text to send...",
                                      style=wx.TE_CENTRE)
        main_box_v.Add(self._user_text, proportion=0, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)
        button = wx.Button(panel, label="Send user text.")
        button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._user_send_text)
        main_box_v.Add(button, flag=wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=10)
        panel.SetSizer(main_box_v)

    def _user_send_text(self, event):
        """Button callback"""
        self._shared_list.user_print(self._user_text.GetValue())
        event.Skip()

    def _on_close(self, event):
        """Stop the separate thread, then destroy the GUI."""
        event.Skip()
        self._thread.stop()
        self.Destroy()


APP = wx.App(0)
SampleFrame()
APP.MainLoop()
```