# Stopping python loop on key pressed

Tags: python, loops

with python 2.7

```
import time, os

def foo():
    try:
        a=0
        while 1:
            os.system("bash command")
            a += 1
            time.sleep(1/30)
        print a
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print "Interrupted!"

foo()
```

I'm running this from a terminal under Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit but i can't stop this infinite loop, why it's not working ?

I would like to have an infinite loop and break it only when the user press some specific key or any key.

Comment: It should work. What is under `# doing stuff`?

Comment: Just for the record, `1/30 == 0`

Comment: @JBernardo why ? how i can express this fraction ?

Comment: It *will* break successfully if you Ctrl+C, but other keypresses won't break your loop.

Comment: @jedwards i have tried every combination, nothing works ...

Comment: @user1717079 In Python2.x you need at least one side of division to be a float point number to avoid integer division: `1.0/30` or `1/30.0`

Comment: I find that the code works, but without the `sleep` for a reasonable duration I have to hold down control-C for awhile to catch it.

Comment: @DSM apparently yes, now that i'm playing with the time.sleep value it's more responsive and i'm allowed to shut down the execution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

Due to the low value of time.sleep() the execution of the loop was almost impossible to stop, apparently with an higher value for the sleep() the application is more responsive to the user input and everything works.

Answer (score 3):

One more approach is Async. user input. In your case a db or a simple file would suffice.

Have a look at this  [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8160632/929210)